# Adding mySQL on windows xp including management tools

Tags: php, mysql, windows, coldfusion

I have a Windows XP Pro SP3 computer that I want to run mySQL on for testing with PHP.

Seems that mySQL 5..5.4 from dev.mysql.com is the last to support XP and I wanted to know if this is the best version I should use.

Also I need a management system like msSQL2008 comes with that will allow me to create, edit and export the databases and tables to my hosted platform.

I am running ColdFusion 9, msSQL2008 and PHP (XAMPP Apache).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voted to close as "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: I didn't see it as off topic as there is really not a lot of solid information on mySQL being as it is open source and thus no real support. StackOverflow is my favorite board with the best answers and I just needed somewhere to start. Will be more careful next time. Tnx, Andy

Comment: I'm not suggesting it's not a valid question, I just don't think it's a valid question *for here*, given the house rules (which I don't necessarily agree with, but hey).

Comment: @Andy I agree with Adam....Welcome to Stockholm.  You'll get your balls stomped on. Just know its nothing personal (even though it sure feels personal).

Comment: thanks people. i get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL Workbench, which is a proper Desktop program for interfacing with MySQL.  I don't know about whats supported on Windows XP anymore, though sometimes it's more to do with the fact that Microsoft have stopped supporting Windows XP and so no one else is going to support it.  I would maybe think of upgrading your OS.

also this isn't really a SO question.

Comment: downloaded and installed mySQL and Workbench from mySQL.com - easy and perfect. tnx Jarede

Answer (score 1):

I can't add just a comment because i don't have enough reputation points, but if you're running XAMPP that comes with PHP myAdmin which will be what you want for the second part of your question. As for the first part, i don't know what version of MySQL will work best on XP, but are you sure you're not already running MySQL as part of XAMPP? Thats what the M stands for in XAMPP! Load up the XMAPP control panel and check.

Comment: I originally just loaded php with xampp and when i tried to add mySQL it wanted to reload every thing. no mySQL only. I used a cloned drive without xampp. It loaded both but the only management tool I could find was the standard xampp control panel for stopping, starting and config. BTW. if u have an issue with ports just add 1 to the default ports (80 and 443 I believe).